# Where is Barbas- I Need Him To Stop Following Me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've gotten the mission "A Daedra's Best Friend" and was given Barbas as a follower- but I told him to stay and went into a dungeon (Twilight Spelunker). He was gone when I came out, and I can't get another follower to come with me until he's gone. Will finishing the quest without him make him go away?

Comment: are you in pc or other console?